# PHP: variables in strings without concatenation

Tags: php, string

If I have a variable $var in this string:
`echo "Hello, there are many $vars";`

Php looks for the `variable $vars` instead of `$var`.

Without concatenation like: `"Hello, there are many $var" . "s";` 

is there another way to do this, like some sort of escaping character?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

In php you can escape variables like so

```
echo "Hello, ${var}'s head is big";
```

or like

```
echo "Hello, {$var}'s head is big";
```

Reference [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) under escape character section

Comment: Funny thing, I knew this too, but when I search for a reference in the php documentation, I can't find any. I'm probably searching wrong, so does anyone have it?

Comment: And then of course I find it - may be useful for reference: http://pa2.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex

Comment: @Joubarc same here, I couldn't find it anywhere in documentation. That's why I asked it here

Answer (score 6):

You can use `{}` to escape your variable properly. Consider the following example:

```
echo "There are many ${var}s"; #Or...
echo "There are many {$var}s";
```

[**Working example**](http://codepad.org/9dy0peOF)

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively you may want to look at sprintf: http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php

The sprintf function allows you to format any type of variable as a string in a specific notation.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I always divide the variables from a string like this: `echo 'Hello, there are many '.$var.'s';`

Mostly because of readability, if you go through your code it's instantly clear where the variables are.

Comment: Harder than it sounds if there's 3 sets of escaped quotes and 5 variables in 1 string

Comment: readability is the exact reason why I prefer the other solution

Comment: That actually depends on your IDE/editor. My editor highlights these variables for me, so I always have readable code. Also, using `{}` to call those variables will give the seam readability effect.

Comment: Maybe I should look at different editors, because I'd highly prefer doing it with brackets if it showed up in my editor.

Comment: @Rikudo, I downloaded the trial and I'm liking it so far. However it doesn't color code the `{$var}` syntax for me, should I download a plugin for that or something?

Comment: It does for me, and no plugins used. See https://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/sSqFtT6OLkT30oNfWANrOlBAFPbq3mohJ6Dj_JvF0H4?feat=directlink Make sure you are using double quotes though, single quotes don't evaluate variables.

Comment: Woops, I've always used single-quotes so didn't stop to think about that. Cheers!