# Made a php variable and now can't run it

Tags: php, variables

Right I had to make a variable as shown below.

```
$questionID = '$quizinfo[\'Q' . $ques_num . '_ID\']';
```

But now the code wont run when shown anywhere it shows like $quizinfo['Q1_ID'] Instead of getting the variable that the php got earlier that behind it.

I need to be done like that as there 15 questions in a quiz and the ids I held and I change the number every time to get the new ID number but it not getting them how do I fix it?

checking it I put in.

```
echo $quizinfo['Q1_ID'];
```

And it worked correctly so what do I need to do to make it work?

Comment: your basic quoting\syntax is wrong

Comment: try with double quotes

Comment: i believe it's tripple quotes he needs to use .. even double won't help .. to be really sure, use the quadro quotes ..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Try:**

```
$questionID = $quizinfo['Q' . $ques_num . '_ID'];
```

It should work.

**When you write:**

```
$questionID = '$quizinfo[\'Q' . $ques_num . '_ID\']';
```

`$quizinfo[…]` is not interpreted. It is taken as a string.

**See also:**

- [Php variables inside strings](http://www.jcxsoftware.com/jcx/node/2335)
- [PHP - concatenate or directly insert variables in string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605965/php-concatenate-or-directly-insert-variables-in-string)
- [PHP: variables in strings without concatenation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7036931/php-variables-in-strings)
- [PHP: Beware of Variables Inside Strings](http://www.gerd-riesselmann.net/php-beware-of-variables-inside-strings)
- [Mixing PHP variable with string literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5368890/mixing-php-variable-with-string-literal)

Answer (score 2):

Since it is just php, why do you escape it?

```
$questionID = $quizinfo['Q' . $ques_num . '_ID'];
```

should do it. Also, You have `]'` which should be replaced by `']` at the end.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking to use a variable for your array index:

```
$index = "Q{$ques_num}_ID";
echo $quizinfo[$index];
```

The problem you're experiencing is that you've turned the whole expression into a string with a number inside it, and so no array look-up was being performed.

As an aside: having indices that are human-readable is nice for humans, but not necessary for a computer. Unless you have a particular need to do it this way, I'd change this so it is just numerically indexed - it'll simplify your code.